# How to deadletter a message in AzureFunction ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: azureservicebus, dead-letter

I'm trying to deadletter a message but can't seems to find the right library:

```
MessageReceiver
ServiceBusReceiver
ServiceBusReceivedMessage
```

I've tried both. Getting runtime errors with all of them.

net6.0 Azure Function

[image]

[image]

Can someone provide a link to an example or some documentation for net6 functions and manual deadlettering?

Comment: What you are looking for is on this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191322/how-to-move-a-service-bus-messge-to-deadletter-in-service-bus-queue-trigger-func)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform message settlement tasks, you'll want to bind to `ServiceBusMessageActions`.  This will give you access to operations such as dead lettering, completion, and abandonment.

For example:

```cs
[FunctionName("BindingToMessageActions")]
public static async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("<queue_name>", Connection = "<connection_name>")]
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages,
    ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
{
    foreach (ServiceBusReceivedMessage message in messages)
    {
        // Dead letter all the things!
        await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(message);
    }
}
```

More examples for using the extensions bindings for various scenarios can be found in the [Examples section](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus-readme#examples) of the overview documentation.

Comment: Note: this will only work with In-Process Functions SDK, not with Isolated Worker SDK.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `azure sdk for .net` for this along with message receiver.

To manually dead letter a message we need to use the `deadletterAsync` method.

```
await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(lockToken);
```

Refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.deadletterasync?view=azure-dotnet) for deadletterAsync .

Comment: This is not the recommended approach and the linked documentation points to a deprecated package.